# Converting MongoDB aggregation pipeline code from Javascript to Python

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

As a newbie in Python/MongoDB/pymongo, I used Studio 3T for generating a working aggregation pipeline for accessing and processing the content of a mongoDB collection. I can see that it works perfectly fine there and outputs the expected result. The problem is that Studio 3T generates a .js file for the code while I need to write the code in Python within a wrapper.

Code executing correctly on Studio 3T:

```
db.cln_matching_results.aggregate(

// Pipeline
[
    // Stage 1
    {
        $unwind: {
            path : '$_availability',
            includeArrayIndex : 'arrayIndex', // optional
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : false // optional
        }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
        $unwind: {
            path : '$_availability.availability_data',
            includeArrayIndex : 'arrayIndex', // optional
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : false // optional
        }
    },

    // Stage 3
    {
        $match: {
            '_availability.availability_data.start_date': {$gte: "2017-09-14T00:00:00.000Z", $lte: "2017-09-31T00:00:00.000Z"}
        }
    },

    // Stage 4
    {
        $group: {
                   _id : '$_id',
                   MD_offered_max: { $sum: { $divide: [ "$_availability.availability_data.value", 100 ] } }
        }
    },
]);
```

My attempt at replicating the working code within my Python wrapper breaks the pipeline and gives an empty array after execution. I stress that the rest of the python code works perfectly fine when I comment out the piece of code below:

```
    test_pipeline.extend([
    {"$unwind": {'path': '$_availability', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': False}},
    {"$unwind": {'path': '$_availability.availability_data', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': False}},
    {'$match': {'$_availability.availability_data.start_date': {'$gte': "2017-09-14T00:00:00.000Z", '$lte': "2017-09-16T00:00:00.000Z"}}},
    {'$group':{'_id' : '$_id', 'MD_offered_max': { '$sum': { '$divide': [ "$_availability.availability_data.value", 100 ] } }}},
    {'$addFields': {'availability_scoring': '$MD_offered_max'}}
])
```

My question is: where did I go wrong in my attempt at translating the code from a .js format to Python? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's a typo. `'$match': {'$_availability.availability_data.start_date'` should be `'$match': {'_availability.availability_data.start_date'`. Field names cannot be prefixed with `$`. That is reserved for "field path variables" and "operators" as is used elsewhere in the pipeline. That's the difference in the code.

Comment: Also if you intend to filter array elements within the aggregation pipeline then you really "should" be placing the same `$match` condition at the **first pipeline stage as well**. If you do not do that, the proceeding `$unwind` stages ( or any other stages before ) are actually processing documents that cannot possibly match the condition in addition to those that do. This unnecessary work means your aggregation takes significantly more time to execute. Where applicable to "any" filtering, always `$match` first.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that. It works as expected now. Cheers!

Comment: As a follow-up, how can I change the hard-coded date for the '$gte' condition in the aggregation pipeline with "earliest_start_date" where:

"earliest_start_date" : ISODate("2017-09-11T22:00:00.000+0000")

?

Comment: To answer my own question, the ISODate format of "earliest_start_date" cannot be directly compared with the string format of "_availability.availability_data.start_date" using '$gte'. The following conversion is necessary to get the same format as the hard-coded string used in the comparison:

earliest_start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%T.000Z").

Usage of strftime: http://strftime.org/